# filezilla Command: MLSD Response: 500 Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Tags: filezilla, directory-listing

Recently our network was moved to the corporate network and behind the company firewall.
Since the i could not access the FTP Servers using Filezilla. I can connect to them but cannot receive the directory listing.

```
Command: MLSD 
Response: 500 
Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I can access the server using other softwares ( GnomeCommander ) but i would like to use Filezilla for its advanced features.
I tried active and pasive mode but that doesnt work.

I trace the problem to the MSLD command. I think if i could make filezilla use LIST command it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The LIST command is deprecated and MLSD is now used according to standards. Does Filezilla work correctly from a PC outside your network on the same server? If not, this might be a server issue.

Comment: it works, the problem is with our corporate firewall.